# Nonzero reals and cross products are isomorphic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism, group-homomorphism

I have the following question that I am confused by:

Show that the groups $(\mathbb{R}-\{0\},\cdot)$ and $(\mathbb{R},+)\times(\mathbb{Z}_{2},+)$ are isomorphic.

I have been able to show that $(\{1,-1\},\cdot)\simeq(\mathbb{Z}_{2},+)$ and that $(\{1,-1\}\cdot)\times((0,\infty),\cdot)\simeq (\mathbb{R}-\{0\},\cdot)$. How would I finish off this problem? Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 2):

**hint:** Let $\exp:(\mathbb R,+) \to (\mathbb R_{>0},\cdot)$ be the exponential map and note that $$\exp(a+b)=\exp(a) \cdot \exp(b).$$

Comment: How exactly does one include the set $(\mathbb{R},+)\times(\mathbb{Z}_{2},+)$?

Comment: Try to use $-\exp$. What you've shown is that $\mathbb R \times \mathbb Z_{2}$ is most essentially two copies of $(\mathbb R,+)$. What would be the most natural thing to do?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly. Is there some use for the first isomorphism theorem here?